# how to mount a vuejs application on a single url of an existing static website?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, amazon-s3, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a static single page application in the `landing` directory which has the following files and works simply by opening the `index.html` file in the browser.
The directory has the following files and directories:

- index.html
- contactform
- css
- img
- js
- lib

I also have a vuejs application with the following directories and files in the build dist directory:

- css
- favicon.ico
- fonts
- img
- index.html
- js

And the following router.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'login',
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ './views/Login.vue'),
    },
    {
      path: '/manager',
      name: 'manager',
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "manager" */ './views/manager.vue'),
    },
    {
      path: '/staff',
      name: 'staff',
      component: () =>
        import(/* webpackChunkName: "staff" */ './views/staff.vue'),
    },
  ],
});
```

The login page is just a login form which automatically redirects to one of the other pages depending on the user type.
Here is my vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: './',
};
```

I want to deploy this do S3.

Here is what I tried:

I upload the content of landing directory to S3, I put a link like `<a href="login">login</a>` in the index.html of static website and I created a directory called login there and put the content of dist directoy in it. the static website loads fine but the vuejs application doesn't. when I click on login the addressbad changes to `url/login` but the page just reloads. Any thoughts?